# Phalcon: the order of 2 functions "initialize" and "onConstruct" in Controller and Model

Tags: model, controller, phalcon

I check myself and see that, the order of execution on Controller is "onConstruct" then "initialize", while on Model is "initialize" then "onConstruct".

So why the order of execution of these methods is different on Controller and Model? Any idea?

Comment: I check myself and see that, the order of execution on Controller is "onConstruct" then "initialize", while on Model is "initialize" then "onConstruct".

Comment: So why the order of execution of these methods is different on Controller and Model? Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Besides the same name, `initialize` has different purposes in Models and Controllers:

For **Models** initialize will mostly take care of initializing the model's metada(column mapping, model relationships, etc) that's why it's called **before** the constructor since all model metadata is stored statically in the model class (btw that's why `initialize` is called just once per request per model).

For **Controllers** `initialize` is just called if the route is matched successfully(the required action exists and was requested properly) **and** the current user has privileges to execute that action according to the [ACL](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/acl.html)(if any). So the controller is constructed first to check those things (`onConstruct` is fired), and then if everything goes well you can initialize your controller for real (`initialize` is fired).

---

Now talking about `onConstruct`, both in Models and Controllers, that's just a replacement for native constructors. The implementation of a `__construct` method in your classes [**isn't recommended**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/controllers.html#initializing-controllers) because they will be called by the framework that expects a specific method signature for it. Also you'll need to remember to always hook the parent constructor manually. So, by using the `onConstruct` event instead we're avoiding all these issues.