# What did I do wrong here with this SigninController

Tags: php, phalcon

I am constructing a login page with phalconphp and when I clicked on the sign in button with or without any input this error showed:

> Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception: Action 'signin' was not found on
>   handler 'signin' 
>   File=C:\xampp\htdocs\learning-phalcon\public\index.php  Line=97  #0
>   [internal function]:
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher->_throwDispatchException('Action  'signin'...',
>   5)  #1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()  #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\learning-phalcon\public\index.php(97):
>   Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()  #3 {main}

The main point here is that I do not get why I am required to have a signinAction when I did not call that action within my code. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

This is my SigninController:

```
<?php

use \Phalcon\Tag;

class SigninController extends BaseController
{
public function onConstruct()
{
    parent::initialize();
}

private function _createUserSession(User $user)
{
    $this->session->set('id', $user->id);
    $this->session->set('role', $user->role);
    $this->response->redirect("dashboard/index");
} 

public function indexAction()
{
    Tag::setTitle('Signin');
    $this->assets->collection('additional')->addCss('css/signin.css');
}

public function doSigninAction()
{
    if ($this->security->checkToken() == false) {
        $this->flash->error('Invalid CSRF Token');
        $this->response->redirect("signin/index");
        return;
    }

    $this->view->disable();

    $email = $this->request->getPost('email');
    $password = $this->request->getPost('password');
    $user = User::findFirstByEmail($email);

    if ($user)
    {
        if ($this->security->checkHash($password, $user->password))
        {
            $this->_createUserSession($user);
            return;
        }
    }

    $this->flash->error('Incorrect Credentials');
    $this->response->redirect("signin/index");
}

}
```

And this is my signin index page:

```
{% block content %}
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="{{ url('signin/doSignin') }}">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address"   autofocus>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign in">
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ security.getTokenKey() }}" value="{{ security.getToken() }}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Would that be the case? Because I am thinking if my {{ url('signin/doSignin') }} didn't connect properly to the controller.  edit: I changed the cases afterward still nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of possible problems and some recommendations for the code you've posted:

**1)** I'd recommend to name your "base controller" as `ControllerBase`, not only because [**Phalcon conventions**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/controllers.html#creating-a-base-controller) but also one may access your "/base" path.

**2)** I'm worried about this block:

```
public function onConstruct()
{
    parent::initialize();
}
```

Please refer to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660613/phalcon-the-order-of-2-functions-initialize-and-onconstruct-in-controller-a/23732622#23732622) to understand why.

**3)** Here you're using a direct flash within a redirection:

```
$this->flash->error('Invalid CSRF Token');
$this->response->redirect("signin/index");
```

For a **redirection** use `flashSession` instead, unless you meant to **forward** the request to another controller. More info about this **[here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html#implicit-flush-vs-session)**.

**4)** Just another recommendation. It's rare, but using upper case chars in your URIs **can** lead to some problems (mostly human errors). As general recommendation leave case-sensitive parts to the query string only, but that's up to you to decide. With Phalcon you can use dashes in actions names to get it converted for camel case later (just like Phalcon already does for controller names). If you choose to accept this recommendation here's [**more info about it**](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/355/camelcase-actions).

Please, consider at least the first two items, then give me some feedback if your problem isn't solved.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations I will definitely check them out.